# Overwrite an existing JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, global

I have an existing global JavaScript function called GlobalAll(). This function is loaded on every page by default in the  section.
`function GlobalAll(){alert("I am Global!");}`
This function doesn't return anything. On some of the pages, I want to redefine this function so it alerts "I am Local!" instead or doesn't alert at all. The function name needs to stay the same as it is complicated than just alerting something.

So, technically what we need is to rewrite/overwrite this global function and call it with the same name in specific pages.

Any solutions?

Comment: Overwriting a function in Javascript is as simple as redeclaring it in a context that shares the scope (globally, this means anywhere, although `window.globalAll = function(){...}` is needed to define it everywhere from an inner scope). *Why* you'd want to do this is a different matter; it seems like bad design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the DOM loads sequentially from top to bottom, just redefine it somewhere below where you originally defined it.

So:

```
<body>

<script src="something.js"></script> <!-- defines GlobalAll() -->
<script>    
  function GlobalAll() {
    alert('I am local');
  }
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately we don't have access to the global JavaScript file. And this wouldn't work because we only want to redefine this function in some of the pages. We have tried redefining the function in  the specific pages, but it wouldn't replace the previous function.

Comment: Defining this in a page somewhere below where it's originally defined will most definitely overwrite it, it doesn't even have to be in the same global javascript file. @hos______

Comment: @hos______ - It's possible to ["redefine in scope"](http://jsfiddle.net/nLhwr5dr/1/), but this doesn't change the references already associated with the previous function; you would have to modify the global declaration for that.

Comment: Thanks again. We found that the issue was that the redefinition was in a document.ready function and we were calling this global function in another document.ready function. And as the document.ready functions were executed asynchronously the re-definition was not executed when the function was called. We moved the re-definition and the call to the same document.ready and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the specialized behaviour for GlobalAll on each individual page. Just make sure that the new definition comes after the old one and javascript should use the newer definition.

Answer (score 0):

Let's support you have a javascript file called global.js. Inside that, you have a `GlobalAll` function:

```
function GlobalAll() {
    alert("I am Global");
}
```

let's suppose you have this html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/global.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

You are calling `GlobalAll` somewhere, so you must have something like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/global.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            GlobalAll();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

this alerts `I am Global`. You need to override the function after it was initially defined, to make sure that your local function overrides the global and you need to override the function before you call it, to make sure that when it is called, the right instance is used:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/global.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function GlobalAll() {
                alert("I am Local");
            }
            GlobalAll();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```